# How to link react-native-vector-icons to project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am getting a build error with the react-native-icons. I did the linking command from the installation instructions from their github site. the message said the icons were already linked to the project.

> Ld /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativeStarter.app/NativeStarter normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/rsanchez/Development/NativeStarter.git/ios
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Intermediates/NativeStarter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativeStarter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NativeStarter.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lRNVectorIcons /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Intermediates/NativeStarter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativeStarter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NativeStarter_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rsanchez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeStarter-ddtqngxgxoergggtejjrwdqafazh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativeStarter.app/NativeStarter
>
> ld: library not found for -lRNVectorIcons
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have updated the docs of [Native Starter Pro](http://strapmobile.com/native-starter-pro/). Please check the first question under FAQs

http://strapmobile.com/docs/native-starter-pro/faqs/

**Probabilities:**

- This might be the problem if you have 'npm3' installed in your system.
- Make sure you have installed 'npm2'.
- Linking the Vector Icons repo in XCode will solve the issue

**Solution 1: Drag-drop to link RN Vector Icons files:**

- In your finder / computer, navigate to (project folder) -> node_modules -> react-native-vector-icons
- Drag the RNVectorIcons.xcodeproj to the Libraries in the sidebar as explained in the image below
  [image]

**Solution 2: Manually link the RN Vector Icons files:**

- Go to 'Build Phases' in Xcode
- Link Binaries with Libraries by clicking on '+'
- Click on 'Add Other'
- Navigate to 'NativeStarter' (project folder) -> node_modules -> react-native-vector-icons
- Select 'RNVectorIcons.xcodeproj'
- Clean Build
- Build Again

Answer (score 4):

What that i have done is just follow documentation in github.

I just run `rnpm link` and it work without did it manually.

Please make sure that you have install 'rnpm'

```
npm install rnpm -g
```

Comment: Helped me out a lot. Thanks